# How long does an iPhone alarm last?

Tags: iphone, alarm

I lost my iphone but the alarm is still on and I want to know if the alarm turns itself off or if someone calls the iPhone will the alarm turn off.

Answer (score 1):

The alarm will last about 15 minutes, according to [Anna Fyen](https://www.quora.com/For-how-long-does-an-iPhone-alarm-persist-until-it-turns-off-on-its-own)'s answer on Quora:

> My alarm works fine every weekday. I cannot give you the exact time. But one day, I set an alarm and let it ring for a while so after about 15 minutes or so of ringing it turns itself off and displays a message on the lock screen.

Phoning an iPhone currently playing the alarm will likely interrupt the alarm and replace the sound with that of the ring tone.